# SheetJS won't initilize when injected on page via Chrome Developper console

Tags: google-chrome, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to inject SheetJS into a page with Chrome developer console. But it seemes like it doesn't initilize correctly. It does create an XLSX object but it is empty. Does anyone know how to get this working?
The script is injected into the page like this:

```
sheetjsScript.type = "text/javascript";
sheetjsScript.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/sheetjs/sheetjs/dist/xlsx.full.min.js";
$("head").append(sheetjsScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

Newermind, I figured it out.. The target page is using requireJs and that made it throw an error. Instead I injected the script with require:

```
require(["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/sheetjs/sheetjs/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"], function(XLSX) {
    /* use XLSX here */
});
```